# Cannot spread array to pass as multiple arguments

Tags: go

I have this:

```
methods := [...]string{"POST", "PUT"}
router.HandleFunc(h.makeRegisterNewUser("/api/v1/register", v)).Methods("POST", "PUT")
```

that works except `methods` is unused. If I try this:

```
methods := [...]string{"POST", "PUT"}
router.HandleFunc(h.makeRegisterNewUser("/api/v1/register", v)).Methods(methods...)
```

I get this error:

> cannot use methods (type [2]string) as type []string in argument to
>   router.HandleFunc(h.makeRegisterNewUser("/api/v1/register",
>   v)).Methods

I can't figure this one out

Comment: Slice are common in Go, arrays are not. Don't use arrays unless there is a compelling reason. Your code has no reason for an array.

Comment: @Volker more about why it wasn't working, maybe show how to do with with a slice instead, for the newbs like me?

Comment: Why it doesn't work: The language forbids it. Variadic arguments _require_ a slice: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters . It is worth reading the language specification: It is clear, short and understandable. How to do with a slice: See ssemilla's answer: No ...

Comment: there must be some very good reason why it works for a slice but an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `...` in `methods := [...]string{"POST", "PUT"}`

```
 methods := []string{"POST", "PUT"}
```

Edit:
Arrays are slightly different from slices. The `[...]` notation creates an array while a variadic function like `Methods()` accepts a slice. If you really need an array you can take a slice of it using `[:]`:

```
router.HandleFunc(h.makeRegisterNewUser("/api/v1/register", v)).Methods(methods[:]...)
```

Comment: `[...]string{"POST", "PUT"}` created an array of string with size of 2. That is why you are getting "type [2]string" in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion arises from little bit different naming in Go and other languages. The data structure that resembles an array with different length and is called as "array", "vector", "list" in miscellaneous languages in Go is called "slice". And "array" in Go is another thing - a structure of fixed length.